# Kdenlive renders title clips as text w/ black backgrounds (preview is correctly transparent w/ alpha)

Tags: kdenlive

I've tried many different video export formats, but the result is always the same:

- Audio is fine
- Text is fine
- Background doesn't show video, it's just pure black

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do it. I had to go to Render > More Options > Render using Proxy Clips (Also I happend to use lossless FFV, a.k.a *.mkv)

Not sure why it required me to use proxy clips but it did. Probably because the clips were raws from a android/iphone app called Marco Polo which may have had some odd encoding to them.

Comment: didn't work for me, even with "proxy clips" still black background with titles

Comment: @AJN Did you try with lossless FFV, a.k.a *.mkv?

Another thing I'd try is use Handbrake to re-encode the video for testing purposes and then see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jonathan-leaders -- I also tested FFV and reencoded with Handbrake: look here ----    https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzYXUSsUVFR_VDhzM0ZiSExVZE0/view

Comment: Hmm, at this point I may suggest submitting a bug to kdenlive: https://kdenlive.org/bug-reports/